# How to get a uiview to be displayed on button click in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an application in which i have a uiview which has a two buttons on it.  i have set the frame of my uiview like this.

```
newview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,350,320,70)];
```

and set it to my main view

```
[self.view addSubview:newview];
```

then to this new view i have added two buttons.  one button on the left side of new and other button of right side of new view.

this is my code for button

```
leftnavbutton= [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
            leftnavbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [leftnavbutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

UIImage *buttonImageleft = [UIImage imageNamed:@"previous_large.png"];
            //UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];

[leftnavbutton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageleft forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [leftnavbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftnavbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(23, 28, 8, 44)];
            [newview addSubview:leftnavbutton];  



rightnavbutton= [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
            rightnavbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [rightnavbutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

UIImage *buttonImageright = [UIImage imageNamed:@"next_large.png"];
            //UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];            

[rightnavbutton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageright forState:UIControlStateNormal];         

[rightnavbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];           

[rightnavbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(275, 28, 8, 44)];
[newview addSubview:rightnavbutton];
```

so now i want when i click on these buttons. a new view should replace over my new view.
for example now when i run my application in the new view current conditon which is fetched from xml is displayed in that.  So when i click on the right button a new view should open which should fetch the forecsat condition tag fron xml and display on it and when i click on the right button it should again display the current condition. i.e it should be in loop.  if i click on the left button againg forecast condition should be shown.  How is this possible?

Comment: Have you implemented play and play action? Also its better to have controllers for each view.

Comment: @praveen no i have not implemented play action

Comment: View controllers would work much better and be easier to implement for sure. Try it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is replace `newView` with another view. To do that, you should first set the newView's `tag`.

```
newview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,350,320,70)];
newView.tag = 7; // set whatever number you want
[self.view addSubview:newview];
```

In `playAction`, get hold of the `newView` and remove it from the `superView`. Then add another view in its place.

```
-(void)playAction:(id)sender
{
     UIView* newView = [self.view viewWithTag:7];
     [newView removeFromSuperView];

     //create and add the new new view that should replace new view. Use the same frame.
     UIView* newnewview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,350,320,70)];
     newnewView.tag = 7; // set whatever number you want
     [self.view addSubview:newnewview];

      //Add the left & right buttons again, as they were removed when newView was removed
      ... code to add buttons...
}
```

Similarly the `play:` method can be implemented.

Comment: hi akshay as u told the on button click view class is being called but i have a prob. i am fetching the row values of the tableview and displaying in the uiview but for display purpose the tableview is kept hidden .so when i call the indexpath.row in the switch case my breakpoint does not enter in it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand where a table came in from? I thought you want to change a view when a couple of buttons are pressed.